# Zend Framework 1.2 - Error Table doesn't exists - even though the table already exists in MySQL

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc

We’re on Zend 1.12 https://github.com/Shardj/zf1-future with security and php7.4 compatibility updates.

Since this is a legacy application with very little documentation from the prior developer. I am trying to add/insert data through `Zend` to the `yearly_report_count` MySQL table. I have already created the MYSQL table, but it throws an error when I try to insert the data. The error is

```
SQLSTATE[42S02] : Base table 
or view not found : 1146 Table 'yearly_report_count' doesn 't exist, query was: DESCRIBE `yearly_report_count` though the table is present in database
```

I am not sure if the table has to be defined somewhere in the code? In any model, in some configuration?

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to the correct database? If yes, are you sure that 'yearly_report_count' exists n the correct schema? To help you this error is not enough, you should post the code where you execute this query and how you make the DB connection

Comment: @SergioRinaudo right the database was not connected to the correct DB, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The database was not connected to the correct DB, it is fixed, now.